# Lex tutorial not using specified lambda function for fulfillment

Tags: amazon-lex

I'm trying the lex tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-bp-create-bot.html) and when I get to the point of switching fulfillment to a webhook, it doesn't seem like it's invoking the webhook, and it's completing as if it was not configured to use it.

I have selected the Lambda function as fulfillment for the intent and hit build a a dozen times. Not sure what else I'm supposed to do.

I'm coming from the google side of things so while I think I have a general understanding of how things should work, i have little experience in the amazon stack and its possible that my preconceptions are throwing me off somehow.

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue? The first question I'd ask is whether you've been able to confirm that the lambda function is indeed getting called. You can tell this by checking the monitoring stats for the lambda in question and/or checking the logs in CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate Lambda "code hook" (webhook) options.

The first is "Lambda initialization and validation" near the middle.
- This sets the Lambda function up as the one that Lex will pass data to every turn of the conversation.

The second is "Fulfillment" towards the bottom.
- This sets the Lambda function up as the one that Lex will pass data to only when Lex is ready to fulfill the intent and close it.

It is common practice to set them both to the same Lambda Function.

[image]